# Problem in posting message on facebook wall using android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

I have an module to post predefined messages in my application, till last week it worked perfectly. But now the problem is I could not see the message which i pass in the bundle in the post message pop up, the textbox is blank. Then I come to know that the message key used to send plain text through the bundle got ignored by the facebook sdk itself, please refer the below link

```
[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/][1]
```

In the page see the message keyword info. Now I want to post some plain content through my application.Anybody know how to solve this problem, please share with me.

Thanks in Advance,
Rajapandian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, which I used in an app for fixing this problem was quite easy. Not sure if it will help you though. But instead of using the message param since it's ignored I used the name of a link.

So I just shared a link to the homepage of the app (the owner of the apps company) and put name, link and picture so I could use a nice logo for the wall post. You could use a market link or whatever.com