# How do I publish a score and a link to Facebook now that the "message" field is no longer available?

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Android game where I wish to publish to FB the user's result plus a link to the game itself.  Since the "message" field is no longer available, how do I go about doing it?

I tried looking at the examples that come with the API but they were of little help.

A nice, simple example would be a real help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ and make your choice. 
As I have answered here: [Problem in posting message on facebook wall using android facebook sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076787/problem-in-posting-message-on-facebook-wall-using-android-facebook-sdk/7076830#7076830)

I would actually post a link and instead of using the message you could use the name, even caption if you would like. Using the name that will be the main text of the link. So you will still get a link to whatever you want.

Comment: Problem is that the "message" parameter is no longer supported. I want to be able to post something like "I played this game and scored xxxxx points. Why not try it and see if you can beat me?". Then I want to add a link to my app.

Comment: I just told you how you should do it. INSTEAD of using message use the "name" parameter. Read my answer again.

Comment: Ooops. Off to buy some new glasses!

Comment: What does it mean when it says that the app_id is required, but "automatically specified by most SDKs". Should I register an application on FB and use that?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a Facebook application, which will be used to post on the user's behalf (once user permits the application to do so).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is still a valid solution: 
[Post on user's friends facebook wall through android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application#answer-5898193)

For own wall, you'd obviously use the "me" part in the request.